# Polar Coordinate function of a Straight Line

Tags: geometry, functions, trigonometry

I was having some problem when trying to come out a polar coordinate function with straight line equation.

*I know it is not good to post images here, but please bear with me as the question requires us to solve the equation from the straight line in the image.*

What I have done is I tried to come out with an implicit function for the straight line L.

```
2x + 3y - 6 = 0
```

But then I not sure how can I continue from there to come out with a polar coordinate function. Any ideas?

Thanks!

[image]

Comment: Are you familiar with the polar coordinate system?

Comment: @Triatticus Not exatly but I know x = r cos (angle), y = r sin (angle)

Comment: That's the idea, substitute and solve for r

Comment: I see I see thanks so much!!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

$x = r\cos \theta\\
y = r\sin\theta\\
2x + 3y - 6 = 0\\
2r\cos\theta + 3r\sin\theta = 6\\
r(2\cos\theta + 3\sin\theta) = 6$

Now I could say:

$r = \frac {6}{3\cos\theta + 2\sin\theta}$

and be done.

But I think that this is a little bit more informative:

$\sin (\arctan \frac ab) = \frac {a}{\sqrt {a^2 + b^2}}\\
\cos (\arctan \frac ab) = \frac {b}{\sqrt {a^2 + b^2}}$

$r\sqrt {2^2 + 3^2}(\sin (\arctan \frac{3}{2})\sin\theta + \cos(\arctan \frac 32)\cos\theta) = 6\\
r\sqrt {13}(\cos(\theta - \arctan \frac 32)) = 6\\
r\sqrt {13}(\cos(\theta - \arctan \frac 32)) = 6\\
r = \frac {6}{\sqrt {13}} \sec (\theta - \arctan \frac 32)$

As it gives the angle of rotation and the distance to the line.

Comment: I think your cosine and sine for when substituting into x and y were upside down :)

Comment: @guest176969 thanks

Answer (score 5):

In Cartesian coordinates, a straight line equation is $y=mx+b$ where is $m$ is a numerical slope and $b$ is a numerical $y$ intercept.  Following  rules for converting to polar coordinates, we let $x=r\cdot cos\theta$ and $y=r\cdot sin\theta$.   Solve for $r$  $$\left\{ r=-\frac{b}{m\;\operatorname{cos}\left(\theta\right)-\operatorname{sin}\left(\theta\right)}\right\}$$

I typically use $0\le\theta\le 2\pi$  The idea of graphing a line in polar coordinates is more of a curiosity to me than anything practical.  In Geogebra, (for example) there is not really a polar graphing system, but we can plot a polar equation by conversion to cartesian. that is, $x=r(\theta)\cos\theta$ and $y=r(\theta)\sin\theta$.  Geogebra then superimposes a polar grid and viola it looks like we have graphed a polar  equation.  So... No real restriction on $r$, except that $\theta$ will have to have exceedingly high precision at certain points in its range or you will jump over the large values of $r(\theta)$. I would have to play with this awhile to give you any better answer.

Comment: I see I see thanks so much!

Comment: Just wondering after the equation is expressed in polar form, are there any restrictions on r and $\theta$?

Comment: @Will Kim  I added an explanation to my answer.  I wouldn't fit in comments.

Answer (score 3):

The straight line through $(0,2)\text{ and } (3,0)$ has equation $$y=-\frac{2}{3}x+2$$
Since the the polar coordinates $(r,\alpha)$ correspond to $(r\sin\alpha,r\cos\alpha)$ this translates to $$
-\frac{2}{3}r\cos\alpha = r\sin\alpha+2$$

It only remains to solve for $r$.

Answer (score 0):

Given the linear equation in two intercept form, $\frac{x}{a}+\frac{y}{b}=1$.

The equivalent polar form is $r=\frac{a*b*\sec(θ)}{b+\tan(θ)}$. Note, however, that $r=\frac{a*b}{b*\cos(θ)+a*\sin(θ)}$ requires one more variable lookup but is well-defined when $θ=π*n, n\in\mathbb{Z}$, instead of involving a division by $0$.

Answer (score 0):

If  $\alpha $ is CCW angle made to the normal then in Cartesian form ( not exactly as shown in your question, it should be normal to the line L.
$$ x \cos\alpha + y \sin  \alpha = p $$

and in polar coordinates after transformation

$$ r = p \sec \left( \theta - \tan^{-1} \frac{a}{b} \right ) $$

Answer (score 0):

Note also that (following from [Niel's answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4032587)'s that $\frac{x}{a}+\frac{y}{b}=1\iff r=\frac{a*b}{b*\cos(θ)+a*\sin(θ)}$) the Cartesian equation for the line joining two points $((x_0,y_0),(x_1,y_1))$ is $a=\frac{x_1*y_0-x_0*y_1}{y_0-y_1}, b=\frac{y_1*x_0-y_0*x_1}{x_0-x_1}$, so the polar equation is $\frac{\frac{x_1*y_0-x_0*y_1}{y_0-y_1}*\frac{y_1*x_0-y_0*x_1}{x_0-x_1}}{\frac{y_1*x_0-y_0*x_1}{x_0-x_1}*\cos(θ)+\frac{x_1*y_0-x_0*y_1}{y_0-y_1}*\sin(θ)}=\frac{x_0*y_1-x_1*y_0}{(y_1-y_0)*\cos(θ)+(x_0-x_1)*\sin(θ)}$.