# How to convert from cartesian to polar equation with no intercept

Tags: polar-coordinates

I want to convert the equation $y=2x$ from cartesian form to polar form. I found already a couple of other topics regarding this f.e.[Polar Coordinate function of a Straight Line](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2736228/polar-coordinate-function-of-a-straight-line)

but they all have a the function in the form of $y = mx+c$
Since I have no $c$ and i use the convertion formulas $y = r \sin(t)$ and $x = r \cos(t)$ when substituting

I get

$r \sin(t) = 2 r \cos(t)$

and then the $ r$ can be scrapped leading to

$\sin(t) = 2 \cos(t)$

or $0 = 2\cos(t)/\sin(t)$

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you sure that $0=2 \frac{cos(t)}{sin(t)}$ ? When you divide,  you get zero or 1 ?

Answer (score 1):

Your algebra is incorrect. The proper rearrangement of the equation
$$\sin \theta = 2 \cos \theta$$
is$$
\tan \theta = 2.$$